# Enzyme shallow render always tries to render root index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I started to develop an app and the first batch of tests have several tests like this to test if a component renders:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import NavLink from 'components/sidebar/NavLink';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(NavLink);
  expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
});
```

[EDIT] Also this test fails:

```
import { take } from 'redux-saga';
import fetchSaga from 'store/events/saga';
import { types } from 'store/events/reducer';

it('should know Events where requested', () => {
  const gen = fetchSaga();
  expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(take(types.EVENTS_REQUESTED));
});
```

I tried this approach with various components but they always fail with:

```
FAIL  src/components/sidebar/navLink/NavLink.test.jsx
● Test suite failed to run

  Expected the reducer to be a function.

  at createStore (node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:97:11)
  at node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:561:31
  at createStore (node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:93:33)
  at configureStore (src/store/configureStore.js:10:40)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.jsx:9:44)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/parse5/lib/parser/parser_stream.js:5:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/parse5/lib/index.js:41:24)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/lib/parse.js:5:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/lib/cheerio.js:5:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/index.js:5:28)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:13:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/build/index.js:1:110)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-matchers/lib/assertions/toContainReact.js:7:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-matchers/lib/index.js:19:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js:5:23)
  at handle (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
  at process.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:51:3)
  at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
  at process.emit (events.js:213:7)
  at emit (internal/child_process.js:774:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

The only place where `configureStore` is used is in `Index.jsx`, located in the app's root directory:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider as StoreProvider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const initialState = { events: { entities: [], result: {} } };
const store = configureStore(initialState);

ReactDOM.render((
  <StoreProvider store={store}>
     <App />
  </StoreProvider>), document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

It makes no sense to me why `shallow` would try to render the full app when it's supposed to avoid precisely that

Any idea of what is going on? I feel is one of those lame easy things but don't seem to find what it is